# Mutual Friends Facebook Call Seems to be Timing Out

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to make the following graph call using the Facebook iOS SDK:

```
me/mutualfriends/<friend_id>
```

Using the call:

```
NSString* mutualFriendsCall = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"me/mutualfriends/%@", friend_id];
[[delegate facebook] requestWithGraphPath: mutualFriendsCall andDelegate:self];
```

This works sometimes but often (quite often) returns the following error:

```
Error message: An unknown error occurred
```

Other calls such as me/friends work almost a 100% of the time.

What might be causing this difference?

Update:
This also is reproducable if you just call the graph api directly, so it is probably not specific to iOS. 
 https://graph.facebook.com/me/mutualfriends/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appeared to be a facebook bug which has since been fixed.